# React Native app shows -- signinwithemailandpassword failed: First argument “email” must be a valid string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-native

When i launched the and hit on the login button it shows the above error. but It should says "Authentication Errror"
​when i successfully logged in and then log out then if i make any field blank app does not show error then .
​Ho can i solve it ?? Codes are below  here of Login.js .
​Please have a look on my Code .

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react' ;
    import  {AppRegistry , ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Text, View,Image,StatusBar , TouchableWithoutFeedback, TextInput, Keyboard, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity ,KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native' ;
    import firebase from 'firebase' ;
    import Button from './Button' ;
    import Spinner from './Spinner' ;
    import OrderPageNav from './OrderPageNav';
    import {StackNavigator}  from 'react-navigation';
    import Header from './Header' ;
    import OrderList from './OrderList';


    export default class Login extends Component{
        static  navigationOptions ={       
            header:null,
        };

        state ={ email:'', password:'', error:'', loading:false };
        state ={loggedIn:null};

        componentWillMount(){
            firebase.initializeApp({
                apiKey: "AIzaSyD2lZmC5t-eBCZ6PIfdPX654WG8gBphMpU",
                authDomain: "dotsp-731e5.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://dotsp-731e5.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "dotsp-731e5",
                storageBucket: "dotsp-731e5.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "732705943561"
            });
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) =>{
                    if(user){
                        this.setState({loggedIn:true});
                    }else{
                        this.setState({loggedIn:false});
                    }   
            });
        }

        onButtonPress(){
            const {email,password} =this.state;
            this.setState({error:'' , loading:true  });
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )
            .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
            .catch(() =>{
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
                .catch(this.onLoginFailed.bind(this));
            });
        }
        onLoginFailed(){
            this.setState({
                error:'Authentication Failed',
                loading:false
            });
        }
        onLoginSuccess(){
            this.setState({
                email:'',
                password:'',
                loading:false,
                error:''
            });
        }
        renderButton(){
            if(this.state.loading ){
                return <Spinner size="large" />;

            }else{
                return(
                    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}  >
                        Log In
                    </Button>
                )
            };  
        }
        renderContent(){   
            switch(this.state.loggedIn){
                case true:
                return(
                    <View  style={styles.logocontainer}>
                        <Image style={styles.logo}  source={require('../components/img/logo.png')} />
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('OrderList')} >
                            <Text style={styles.goOrderbtn}>
                                Go to Order List 
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut() } >
                            <Text style={styles.logOutBtn} >
                                Log Out
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>
                );

                case false:
                return(
                    <View style={styles.logocontainer} >
                        <Image style={styles.logo}  source={require('../components/img/logo.png')} />
                        <Text style={styles.logintitle}> Account Information  </Text>
                        <TextInput 
                                placeholder ='Enter your username'
                                placeholderTextColor ='#ffffff'
                                value = {this.state.email}
                                onChangeText ={email => this.setState({email})}
                                style={styles.username}
                                returnKeyType ='next'      
                                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'    
                                autoCorrect ={false}
                                onSubmitEditing ={() => this.refs.txtpassword.focus()}                  
                        />
                        <TextInput style={styles.userpass}
                                placeholder ='Enter your password '
                                placeholderTextColor ='#ffffff'
                                value = {this.state.password}
                                onChangeText ={password => this.setState({password})}
                                returnKeyType ='go'
                                secureTextEntry
                                autoCorrect ={false}       
                                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                                ref ={'txtpassword'}          
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.notifytext}>
                                {this.state.error}
                            </Text>
                        {this.renderButton()}
                    </View>
                );

                default:
                return <Spinner size="large" />;
            }
        }

        render(){      
            return(
                <View style={styles.containerlogin} >
                    <StatusBar backgroundColor="#602D2F" barStyle="light-content"/> 
                    {this.renderContent()}  
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        goOrderbtn:{
            color:'#923438',
            alignItems:'center',
            backgroundColor:'#F7E3DE',
            width:200,
            paddingVertical:10,
            textAlign:'center'
        },
        logOutBtn:{
            color:'#923438',
            alignItems:'center',
            backgroundColor:'#F7E3DE',
            width:200,
            paddingVertical:10,
            marginTop: 30 ,
            textAlign:'center',
            justifyContent:'flex-end'
        },
        containerlogin : {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#923438',
            flexDirection: 'column',
        },
        logocontainer : {
            flex :1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent :'center',
        },
        logo : {
            height : 150 ,
            width: 150,
        },
        logintitle : {
            textAlign : 'center',
            color :'#ffffff',
            fontSize :20,
        },
        username :{
            width : 300,
            height : 60,
            marginTop : 15 ,
            borderWidth : 1 ,
            borderColor : '#ffffff',
            borderRadius : 8,
            color : '#ffffff' ,
            fontSize : 16,
            padding : 10,
            opacity : 0.7,

        },

        userpass :{
            width : 300 ,
            height : 60 ,
            marginTop : 15 ,
            borderWidth : 1 ,
            borderColor : '#ffffff',
            borderRadius : 8,
            color : '#ffffff' ,
            fontSize : 16,
            padding : 10,
            opacity : 0.7,

        },
        loginbutton :{
            paddingVertical : 15 ,
            backgroundColor : '#F0E2DA' ,
            marginTop : 20 ,
            width : 300 ,

        },
        buttonText : {
            color :'#9E494D' ,
            alignItems : 'center' ,
            textAlign : 'center' ,
            borderRadius : 5 ,
            fontWeight : 'bold'
        },
        notifytext : {
            color:'#ffffff',
            fontSize:20
        },
    });
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should be using the react-native-firebase library instead of directly implementing the web sdk.

Comment: Will use it  surely in future .Will you please look at the current issue please ?

Comment: @Christian i am using redux saga firebase and it is causing the same issue ! Any idea about that

Comment: @AliYarKhan I have never used that library, but like I mentioned previously, this is a bug with Firebase itself, so any other wrapper libraries will also have the same bug in Android. Simply add your own validation so that the user can't submit an empty form.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is actually a bug with firebase. Pretty much what happens is that on Android you cannot catch that error. On iOS it works as expected. You basically need to implement your own validation to disable the button until the email and password are not empty.

Comment: As i am new at react-native ,
is react-native-android also does the same error ?

Comment: This is just a firebase bug. signInWithEmailAndPassword() will throw different errors based on the sent values: email doesn't exist, incorrect password, etc. But in the case of an empty email or empty password, it SHOULD throw an error (which you could then handle in the catch() clause), but instead it crashes the app. That's an error with firebase. To get around it, just disable the login button if the email or password is empty.

Comment: Thanks for this comment

Comment: when i logged once time and then log out .After that if i put blank field and try login it shows the error message  "Authentication failed"  that i saved .
so that's why 
can you write me a code that i can disable the login button before input .??

Comment: Has firebase fixed this in the web SDK yet?